# read datatable column based on condition c#

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I have a datatable with some modified rows,  now i want to read the datatable with condition based on those modified rows.

```
    row["Balance"] = dri["Balance"];
    dri.Close();
    DTRecord.AcceptChanges();
    row.SetModified();
}

//here i want to check that read where Balance is >0 

rd.SetDataSource(DTRecord);
```

Comment: Unclear what you asking for?

Comment: actually i was populating some of my my datatable columns from two different tables and wasn't sure how to put condition on those columns,but i got my answer now .. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get those records from Datatable in which Balance is > 0 by this code!

```
DataRow[] dr = dtRecord.Select("Balance > 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ayaz Ulhaq, If we filter the datatable by 2 ways.

1. Datatable.Select(Expression)

   DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Balance > 0");
2. DataView filter

   ```
   DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
   // Filter by an expression. Filter all rows where Balance>0
   dv.RowFilter = "Balance >0 ";
   ```

Comment: both works and rows > 0 selected in dr and dv objects but it wont update the datatable